# Convergence of Partial Sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose we have the series of functions
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{d\!}
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)
$$
where convergence is uniform.
Additionally, consider the partial functions of the series
$$
F_m (x)=\sum_{n=1}^{m} f_n(x)
$$
satisfying the condition
$$
\left\|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{F_m(x)}{x^{3}}\Dm x\right\|<C
$$
for some positive constant $C$, for every $m$.
If it is also true that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} f_n(x)}{x^{3}} \to 0
$$
as $m \to \infty$, can we then claim that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{F_m(x)}{x^{3}}\Dm x \to \int_{0}^{1} \frac{F(x)}{x^{3}}\Dm x
$$
as $m \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :
$$ \int_0^1\frac{F(x)}{x^3}dx-\int_0^1\frac{F_m(x)}{x^3}dx=\int_0^1\frac{F(x)-F_m(x)}{x^3}dx\underset{m\rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$
by hypothesis. You don't need the upper bound assumption nor the uniform convergence, but you do need that your integrals exist, there may be a problem at $0$.

Comment: ok, but if all integrals exist, is the result correct?

Comment: I put the upper limit on the integral of the partial series to say that the integrals are limited.